# Hibernate recursive query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, recursion, hql

My desired query is to get a list of Course objects that belong to a Category.  My objects are as follows:

```
public class Course{
     String name;
     List<Category> categories;
}

public class Category{
     String name;
     Category parent;
}
```

Since the categories reference each other, they can have an infinite depth:

```
A
  A.A
     A.A.A
     A.A.B
  A.B
     A.B.A
B
 B.A
 B.B
C
```

How can I query for courses within the category "A.A", and return all Courses associated with A.A, A.A.A, and A.A.B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you do not know how deep is the tree, you can **use some kind of pattern** as follows

```
select distinct 
    c
from
    Course c
left join fetch 
    c.categories c
where
    c.name like 'A.A%'
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to use native SQL and your database supports recursive common table expressions (basically all major DBMS except MySQL) it's pretty easy:

```
WITH RECURSIVE course_tree (name) AS (
   SELECT name
   FROM course
   WHERE name = 'A.A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT name
   FROM course
   WHERE parent_id = course_tree.id
)
SELECT *
FROM course_tree
```

Comment: Hi. I am building a POC as a interview test and I am trying to use recursive query just like this example. The database is an H2 database (as this is just a POC). The H2 does support recursive queries and I tested it using H2 console. But when creating a native query, it returns NO records. The project is Spring Boot + Spring Data, test H2 instance is in memory. Any input is much appreciated. Thanks.